# Task 39 from iqtest.dk

Tags: pattern

What is the solution for this puzzle from this [IQ test](http://iqtest.dk/main.swf)?

> [image]

Comment: -1. This question is too narrow, not searchable/indexable, unlikely to be of value to future visitors, nor to anyone finding the same puzzle in a different context, let alone a similar/equivalent puzzle anywhere at all.

Comment: @ClickRick, I'm not sure what do you mean. It is the first result among 600000 when you search for "task 39 iq test dk" in google.    
**iqtest.dk** itself is quite famous site, when you search for "iqtest.dk" in google you get 26 millions results.

Comment: @ClickRick and why narrowness is bad? Broadness is bad, as far as I saw on SE and what is documented in FAQ.

Comment: The reason it's an issue is mostly because of the intent of self-answered questions - self-answered questions are good for sharing knowledge, but should really only be used for a specific problem that others will have and be able to find on Stack Exchange. In other words, the question needs to have significant intrinsic value to merit being self-asked and answered.

Comment: @Emrakul, I am tired to disagree, but is it written somewhere or it is your private opinion?  I do not see anything like this here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer . And I do see **exactly the opposite directions** when I follow the first link there:  **"*never hesitate* to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site"**.

Comment: Yeah, @klm, that's true. I guess the main phrase there is "so that others (including yourself) can find it later," which implies they both want to find it and can do so. Let's chat about sometime, but I agree, not now - I'm tired too.

Comment: I asked for this specifically on MetaSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235177/what-are-limitations-on-self-answered-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [kim123](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28/klm123)'s answer is correct, there is a simpler logic shown by colors:

> [image]

shapes are moving and morphing. For instance, the red cross begins its journey from the the upper left crossword box to the the (missing) lower left crossword box. Steps forward and transforms (rotates). The same happens for the blue triangle and the other shapes.

Comment: Hi, I added spoiler markup to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but what is this "simpler logic"? I completelly missing it from your answer. And what does colors means? Why you've highlighted very specivic parts of each picture, each time moving this part exactly by one cell?

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to replace my 2rd and 3rd rule by "each cell moves in the writing direction". That's relly nice improvement. But still you need to explain it in you answer, it is totally unclear, especially because you highlighted a pair of cells, like their relations is important.

Comment: while accepted answer is changed but I believe kim123's answer what the puzzle designer intended.

Answer (score 5):

> The answer is **B**.
>
>  Pictures must be considered consecutively from left to right, from top to bottom.
>  Each picture is obtained from previous by several transformations:
>
>  1. Triangles are changed to crosses. Crosses -> circles. Circles -> triangles.
>  2. 1-st and 2-nd columns are shifted right (become 2-nd and 3-rd columns).
>  3. 3-rd column become 1-st column and circle-shifted down (1-st row become 2-nd, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1).

Answer (score -1):

A simple transformation transforms the patterns in the first column to those in the second and also the patterns in the second column to those in the third.

The three rows are unrelated: each row starts with a new pattern which undergoes the two transformations to get from the first column to the third.

The transformation has been correctly described in previous posts:
 1. Move the nine symbols one cell right, wrapping those on the right to the left but one row down and with the bottom right cell going to top left.
 2. Change crosses to circles, circles to triangles and triangles to crosses.

If the second row were to continue the first row then the patterns in the second row would simply be those in the first row but with all symbols moved down one row. It would be too simple to spot this pattern and would make the answer trivial.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  How does your answer add to the identical ones already given? It seems like all you've done that others haven't is to mention what the puzzle *isn't* and why, but that seems more fitting to add as a comment to another answer, rather than an "answer" on its own.